# Change image in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, resources, android-image

I'm trying to change the image of my listview dynamically.
But I can't figure how to change it because using `setImageResource` doesn't work.

Here's my code snippet:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ImageView imgIco=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgIco);
    Integer id =getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

 if(id==2) {
     String[] valenzeComposti = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.int_valenze);

    // I cannot do this ---------------> imgIco.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico1);
     setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item2,R.id.txtItem, valenzeComposti));
     ListView lv2 = getListView();
      lv2.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      lv2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),InterClassi.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id",(int)id);
                    startActivity(intent);

            }

          });

 }
```

The listview are created as follows -

```
The listview xml (R.layout.list_item2)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dip">

  <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgIco"
                android:layout_width="50dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
               >
   </ImageView>
     ............
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me.. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make you own implementation of ListAdapter. The most common way is extending BaseAdapter. List8 in the API Demos is a good example for making custom ListAdapters.

Answer (score 0):

u may create your **custom list view**  by extending **baseadapter class** to dynamically pass resources to listview. Have a look at this link-http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/
hope this helps.